# Referencing a cell within an iff function in HTML text body (VBA + Outlook) causing problems

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I am new to this, so please excuse my newbie questions. I have the following iff function and the reference to the cell is causing syntax problems and therefore it is not working correctly...

```
Sub test1()
Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo cleanup

    For Each cell In Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "de" Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
       With OutMail
            .To = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
            .Subject = "Your arrival in Vienna " & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value

              .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value _
& IIf(Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value = "incomplete", "<p>Your invoice is incomplete, please find below the payment link:<p/> & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value", "<p> <p/>") 
.Display

        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell


cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If I include the "" between the F in & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value" in says something along list separator or ) - please excuse, my Excel is in German.

If I exclude the "" between the F in writes down the refence & Cells(cell.Row, F).Value as a string and it appears in the email template.

Any ideas? Thank you very very much!

Comment: Thanks for updating.    "something along list separator or ) "  What is the exact error message ? We can attempt a google translate if it is in german.

Comment: It looks like you are actually running this from excel

Comment: It says "erwartet: Listentrennzeichen oder )" and highlights the F. I think it has to do with the Syntax (the "" between the F). Google Translating the error it means expected: list separator or)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the HTML look but

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup

    For Each cell In Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "de" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next

            With OutMail

                .To = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value

                .Subject = "Your arrival in Vienna " & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value

                .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

                .HTMLBody = Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value _
                                                                      & IIf(Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value = "incomplete", "<p>Your invoice is incomplete, please find below the payment link:<p/> " & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value, "<p> <p/>")
                .Display

            End With

            On Error GoTo 0

            Set OutMail = Nothing

        End If

    Next cell


cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```